# Ordenar lista de objetos com PHP

Tags: php, html, order

Boa tarde, eu estou fazendo uma atividade para pegar um pouco mais de jeito com PHP, e resolvi pegar os dados de um arquivo cvs, e mostra-los na tela... até aí ok, consegui. Mas tive a ideia depois de tentar ordenar esses dados atraves de um calculo que eu faço no proprio código, usando dados do arquivo CSV, mas nao estou conseguindo ordena-los, vou deixar o código a seguir.

```
<?php

    $delimitador = ',';
    $cerca = '"';

    // Abrir arquivo para leitura
    $f1 = fopen('$ cat dataset1.csv', 'r');
    $f2 = fopen('$ cat dataset2.csv', 'r');

    if ($f1 && $f2) { 

        // Ler cabecalho do arquivo
        $cabecalho1 = fgetcsv($f1, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
        $cabecalho2 = fgetcsv($f2, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);

        echo "<ol>";
        // Enquanto nao terminar o arquivo
        while (!feof($f1) && !feof($f2)) { 

            // Ler uma linha do arquivo
            $linha1 = fgetcsv($f1, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
            if (!$linha1) {
                continue;
            }
            $linha2 = fgetcsv($f2, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
            if (!$linha2) {
                continue;
            }

            // Montar registro com valores indexados pelo cabecalho
            $registro1 = array_combine($cabecalho1, $linha1);
            $registro2 = array_combine($cabecalho2, $linha2);

            // Verifica quais dos dinossauros são bípedes
            if($registro2['STANCE'] == 'bipedal'){
                // Faz o calculo da velocidade de cada um dos dinossauros bípedes
                $g = 9.8;
                $velocidade = (($registro2['STRIDE_LENGTH'] / $registro1['LEG_LENGTH']) - 1) * SQRT($registro1['LEG_LENGTH']) * $g;

                // Obtendo o nome
                echo "<li>".$registro2['NAME'].PHP_EOL." -> ".$velocidade." m/s²</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ol>";
        fclose($f2);
    }
?>
```

Como eu poderia fazer de maneira dinâmica a lista ordenada ?

**EDIT1**: Oque eu quero fazer, sendo direto, é ordenar os valores do arquivo .csv para que estejam em ordem da maior velocidade até a menor, que seria feito dentro do `if($registro2['STANCE'] == 'bipedal')`. 
Estou começando a aprender a linguagem e não tenho ideia de como fazer essa ordenação.

**EDIT 2**: Vou deixar abaixo exatamento com eu estou fazendo atualmente para voces tentarem reproduzir.

index.php

```
<?php

    $delimitador = ',';
    $cerca = '"';

    // Abrir arquivo para leitura
    $f1 = fopen('$ cat dataset1.csv', 'r');
    $f2 = fopen('$ cat dataset2.csv', 'r');

    if ($f1 && $f2) { 

        // Ler cabecalho do arquivo
        $cabecalho1 = fgetcsv($f1, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
        $cabecalho2 = fgetcsv($f2, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);

        echo "<ol>";
        // Enquanto nao terminar o arquivo
        while (!feof($f1) && !feof($f2)) { 

            // Ler uma linha do arquivo
            $linha1 = fgetcsv($f1, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
            if (!$linha1) {
                continue;
            }
            $linha2 = fgetcsv($f2, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
            if (!$linha2) {
                continue;
            }

            // Montar registro com valores indexados pelo cabecalho
            $registro1 = array_combine($cabecalho1, $linha1);
            $registro2 = array_combine($cabecalho2, $linha2);

            // Verifica quais dos dinossauros são bípedes
            if($registro2['STANCE'] == 'bipedal'){
                // Faz o calculo da velocidade de cada um dos dinossauros bípedes
                $g = 9.8;
                $velocidade = (($registro2['STRIDE_LENGTH'] / $registro1['LEG_LENGTH']) - 1) * SQRT($registro1['LEG_LENGTH']) * $g;

                $array = array("nome" => $registro2['NAME'], "velocidade" => $velocidade);

            }
        }
        echo "</ol>";
        fclose($f2);
    }
?>
```

$ cat dataset1.csv

```
NAME,LEG_LENGTH,DIET
Hadrosaurus,1.2,herbivore
Struthiomimus,0.92,omnivore
Velociraptor,1.0,carnivore
Triceratops,0.87,herbivore
Euoplocephalus,1.6,herbivore
Stegosaurus,1.40,herbivore
Tyrannosaurus Rex,2.5,carnivore
```

$ cat dataset2.csv

```
NAME,STRIDE_LENGTH,STANCE
Euoplocephalus,1.87,quadrupedal
Stegosaurus,1.90,quadrupedal
Tyrannosaurus Rex,5.76,bipedal
Hadrosaurus,1.4,bipedal
Deinonychus,1.21,bipedal
Struthiomimus,1.34,bipedal
Velociraptor,2.72,bipedal
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual. Pedidos de refatoração completa ou código pronto, tutoriais e/ou coisas que envolvem mais de um assunto no mesmo post geralmente não se encaixam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. Se tem dúvida em algum detalhe específico, reduzir o código a um [MCVE] pode ajudar bastante.

Comment: Obrigado pela critica, @Bacco♦, acabei de editar o post, poderia me dar uma ajuda ?

Comment: Tente fazer um [mcve], só com a parte que está com dificuldade. Com esse código todo a gente primeiro teria que entender ele pra depois ver como fazer o que quer, e ainda um baita tutorial explicando o código modificado, o que nao funciona bem no escopo do site. Com um [mcve] e um exemplo de como você tem os dados e como devem ficar, dá para a comunidade entender melhor para talvez viabilizar uma resposta.

Comment: Outra coisa, para ordenar no lugar que disse, do if (ou seja, antes de ter lido todos os registros), teria que buscar a posição certa a todo momento, o que não é uma coisa simples de fazer, envolve várias partes, talvez uma busca binária ou qq outro tipo de indexação (achar o lugar certo pra por o elemento, talvez usando uma lista linkada), complicado para pergunta simples e resposta simples

Comment: entao se eu montasse um array dentro do if e tentasse ordenar depois seria melhor? @Bacco

Comment: Não necessariamente. Se o CSV for longo, ou se for rodar muitos processos em paralelo, vai ter problema de memória. Se for CSV curtinho, o array pode ser uma boa. Se conseguisse fazer um [mcve] com um set de dados de exemplo ajudaria a viabilizar o post.

Comment: @Bacco, voce consegue reproduzir da forma que eu deixei na pergunta? nao consegui fazer um exemplo minimo e virificavel pra deixar aí...

Comment: Reabri, mas sinceramente sem o [mcve] fica complicado pq tem que analisar seu código e tentar entender tudo. Se vc tirasse todas as partes nao importantes, e só deixasse a parte que tem duvida (a que processa o array), facilitaria. Quanto menos código e ruído, melhor.

Comment: Peço desculpas pela forma que deixei @Bacco , sou iniciante, mas acredito que o códgo nao esta tao grande assim. Se puder me dar uma ajuda nisso agradeço. Nas próximas perguntas eu vou tentar colocar um exemplo minimo, agradeço a critica

Comment: Obrigado @AugustoVasques, agradeço a colaboração amigo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer a ordenação que você quer, ordenar os valores do arquivo `.csv` para que estejam em ordem da maior velocidade até a menor(ordem descendente), eu tive que inicialmente criar duas funções.

1 - `velocity($bipedal)` que calcula a velocidade de um bípede com relação entre tamanho do passo, o tamanho da perna e a gravidade, conforme foi dado no exemplo.

2 - `compare_bibedals($a, $b)` que compara a velocidade de dois bípede, e somente bípedes, retornando um inteiro comparativo em ordem descendente, ou seja:

> **$a == $b =>  0**
>
> **$a  < $b =>  1**
>
> **$a  > $b => -1**

Também usei a função [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) que ordena um array pelos valores utilizando uma função de comparação definida pelo usuário, no caso `compare_bibedals`.

Mudei a disposição lógica do código. Inicialmente o código se concentra apenas em extrair os dados dos `.csv`, os arquivos foram lidos de forma independente visando minimizar o uso de recursos. Depois a atividade é focada em trabalhar, separar e ordenar os dados obtidos e então finalizar construindo uma tabela de `HTML`.

```
<?php

    //Calcula a velocidade de um dinossauro bípede
    function velocity($bipedal){
        return (($bipedal['STRIDE_LENGTH'] / $bipedal['LEG_LENGTH']) - 1) * SQRT($bipedal['LEG_LENGTH']) * 9.8;
    }

    //Compara as velocidades de dois dinossauros de forma descendente
    function compare_bibedals($a, $b)
    {   
        // Se as velocidades forem iguais retorna 0
        // Se a velocidade $a < $b retorna  1
        // Se a velocidade $a < $b retorna -1
        if ($a['VELOCITY'] == $b['VELOCITY']) return 0;
        return ($a['VELOCITY'] < $b['VELOCITY']) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    $delimitador = ',';
    $registro = []; // Registro geral onde todos os dados serão mesclados.
    $registro1 = []; // Registro qual será armazenado dataset1
    $registro2 = []; // Registro qual será armazenado dataset2

    // Trabalha individualmente o arquivos dataset1.csv
    $f1 = fopen('dataset1.csv', 'r');
    if ($f1){
       $cabecalho1 = fgetcsv($f1, 0, $delimitador);
        while (!feof($f1)){
            $linha1 = fgetcsv($f1, 0, $delimitador);
            if (!$linha1) {
                continue;
            }
            $registro1[] = array_combine($cabecalho1, $linha1);
        }

    }
    // Terminada as operações com os arquivos eles são fechados para poupar recursos do sistema.
    fclose($f1);

    // Trabalha individualmente o arquivos dataset2.csv
    $f2 = fopen('dataset2.csv', 'r');
    if ($f2){
       $cabecalho2 = fgetcsv($f2, 0, $delimitador);
        while (!feof($f2)){
          $linha2 = fgetcsv($f2, 0, $delimitador);
            if (!$linha2) {
                continue;
            }
            $registro2[] = array_combine($cabecalho2, $linha2);
        }

    }
    // Terminada as operações com os arquivos eles são fechados para poupar recursos do sistema.
    fclose($f2);

    //Mescla os dados obtidos em $registro1 e $registro1 pelo nome
    foreach($registro1 as $dino_info1){
      foreach($registro2 as $dino_info2){
        //Compara ambos registros pelo nome
        if ($dino_info1['NAME'] == $dino_info2['NAME']){
          //Somente os bipedes
          if ($dino_info2['STANCE']!='bipedal') continue 2;
          //Mescla os dois registros
          $bibedal = array_merge((array) $dino_info1, (array) $dino_info2);
          //Adiciona velocidade
          $bibedal['VELOCITY'] = velocity($bibedal);
          //Coloca o resultado no registro geral
          $registro[] = $bibedal;
          continue 2;
        }
      }
    }
    //Ordena o registro geral usando a função compare_bibedals
    usort($registro, "compare_bibedals"); 

    //Imprime uma lista comum com os dados dos dinossauro já ordenada pelo PHP
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($registro as $dino){
      echo "<li>";
      echo "<span>Nome: " . $dino['NAME'] . "</span></br>";
      echo "<span>Dieta: " . $dino['DIET'] . "</span></br>";
      echo "<span>Comprimento do passo: " . $dino['STRIDE_LENGTH'] . "</span></br>";
      echo "<span>Posição: " . $dino['STANCE'] . "</span></br>";
      echo "<span>Comprimento da perna: " . $dino['LEG_LENGTH'] . "</span></br>";
      echo "<span>Velocidade: " . $dino['VELOCITY'] . "</span></br>";
      echo "</li>";
    }        
    echo "</ul>";       

?>
```

Cujo o resultado é :

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Nome: Tyrannosaurus Rex</span></br><span>Dieta: carnivore</span></br><span>Comprimento do passo: 5.76</span></br><span>Posição: bipedal</span></br><span>Comprimento da perna:2.5</span></br><span>Velocidade: 20.205689337412</span></br>
  </li>
  <li><span>Nome: Velociraptor</span></br><span>Dieta: carnivore</span></br><span>Comprimento do passo: 2.72</span></br><span>Posição: bipedal</span></br><span>Comprimento da perna: 1.0</span></br><span>Velocidade: 16.856</span></br>
  </li>
  <li><span>Nome: Struthiomimus</span></br><span>Dieta: omnivore</span></br><span>Comprimento do passo: 1.34</span></br><span>Posição: bipedal</span></br><span>Comprimento da perna: 0.92</span></br><span>Velocidade: 4.2912266412946</span></br>
  </li>
  <li><span>Nome: Hadrosaurus</span></br><span>Dieta: herbivore</span></br><span>Comprimento do passo: 1.4</span></br><span>Posição: bipedal</span></br><span>Comprimento da perna: 1.2</span></br><span>Velocidade: 1.7892270211835</span></br>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Link funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DownrightDeliriousLeads)